# First character of each word in a string

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have a field in an MS Access table that contains people's middle names and I need to get the first letter (initials) of each name in a SQL query. The field is called 'middle_names'

E.g. if the middle_name is 'John David', I want the output to be 'J D'. If the middle_name is 'John', I want the output to be 'J'.

I have found some VBA code that should do this but when I call it in the SQL query I get an error -

> datatype mismatch in criteria expression

The field is of 'text' type and this is the VBA:

```
Function GetFirstLetters(middlename As String) As String
    Dim arr
    Dim I As Long
    arr = VBA.Split(middlename, " ")
    If IsArray(arr) Then
        For I = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            GetFirstLetters = GetFirstLetters & Left(arr(I), 1)
        Next I
    Else
        GetFirstLetters = Left(arr, 1)
    End If
End Function
```

When I then call the code in my SQL query like: `GetFirstLetters(middle_name)` I get the error I mentioned above.

Comment: can't you just find the `space` and get the first character?

Comment: This error could mean that you have some NULL values in your `middle_name` column.

Comment: @trincot Ah yes you are correct. Do you know of any way to get around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your database data has NULL values in the column `middle_name`, then that function call will produce that error, because the function expects a `String` and NULL is not a string.

There are several ways to solve this, one of which is to adapt your query to convert NULL to an empty string before passing it to the function:

```vb
GetFirstLetters(Nz([middle_name], ""))
```

Or, you can keep your original function call, but then your function should accept a `Variant` type argument, and then deal with an Empty value:

```vb
Function GetFirstLetters(middlename As Variant) As String
    If IsEmpty(middlename) Then
        Exit Function
    End If
    ' Rest of your code ...
End Function
```